# how to add a gesture to skView?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I need to add several swipe gestures to my scene on a game. From what I know, this can only be done programmatically, unfortunately I have never added gestures in this way, I have always used IB. I know I need to initialize a gesture recognizer, using `initWithTarget:action:` and I know how to set its properties, what I don't know is how to make this gesture do stuff. I assume it is through the action parameter `@selector` but this seems to never get called. Am I doing this wrong? here is what I have:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(animateSwipeRightLeft)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

and for the selector I have:

```
-(void)animateSwipeRightLeft {

    //do stuff...
}
```

so it comes down to a few related questions: am I setting this up correctly? if so, why is my selector not being called? and if I am wrong about not being able to do this with IB, how?

also, if it helps, my gestures are set up in the initWithSize method for my scene.

Comment: check that self.view isn't nil at the time you are adding the recognizer. It will be nil in the init method of a node.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D it is nil, so how do I fix it?

Comment: add the gesture recognizer after init, or where you create the node that currently contains the addgesturerecognizer code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add gesture recognizers in `SKScene`'s `didMoveToView` method.

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                    action:@selector(animateSwipeRightLeft)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}
```

`self.view` is `nil` inside `init` methods