# Swift3: UISwipeGestureRecognizer in only one of putatively many SKViews

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, skview

## Note:

Prior to asking this question I have viewed and attempted solutions posted for the following questions:

- [gesture recognizer with sprite kit and swift](http://www.spritekitlessons.com/gesture-recognizer-with-sprite-kit-and-swift/)
- [Swift3 iOS - How to make UITapGestureRecognizer trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829151/swift3-ios-how-to-make-uitapgesturerecognizer-trigger-function)
- [how to add a gesture to skView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295734/how-to-add-a-gesture-to-skview)
- [using UIGestureRecognizer with Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial)

## Context:

I have implemented a basic game menu for my game following the example set [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41789989/5623899).

When I reach the `GameScene` I would like to have a `UIGestureRecognizer` that when the screen is swiped up, opens a pause menu. However prior to focusing on the implementation of the pause menu, I foremost need this `UIGestureRecognizer`  to work.

In my `GameScene`, I have added a function:

```
func swipedUp(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("up")
}
```

and inside `override fund didMove(to view: SKView)`:

```
    let swipeUpRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipedUp(_:)))
    swipeUpRecognizer.direction = .up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUpRecognizer)
```

This does not work. For the first line (starts with `let`) I have tried several variants such as:

```
let swipeUpRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedUp"))

let swipeUpRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedUp:"))
```

as well as variations to the `swipedUp` function, e.g.

```
func swipedUp(receiver: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("up")
}
```

## Question

How to add a simple `UIGestureRecognizer` to only *one* `SKView`. I specify one, as due to the implementation of the menu, all the `SKView`s share the same `GameViewController`. Further, the `GameScene` is created only when reached via the menu, and destroyed after the game is over (so making the `GameScene` a global variable will not work either).

Comment: Well, have you add this code to your GitHUB project ('cause I don't see nothing there)?